# Show absolute URL for uploaded file

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I implemented a file upload endpoint with DRF the issue is the documents do not show the absolute url of the file as shown below on the screenshot. I expect the absolute url start with `http://localhost ....`

[image]

**Here is my django settings**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# The folder hosting the files 

STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),]


## Serving the STATIC FILES
# As declared in NginX conf, it must match /src/static/
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)), 'static')


MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

# do the same for media files, it must match /opt/services/djangoapp/media/
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

**models.py**

```
class Document(models.Model):
    """This represents document class model."""
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/inspections/%Y/%m/%d')
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    @property
    def name(self):
        name = self.file.name[33:]
        return name
```

Comment: You can't do this on model level unless you have the access to the `request` object. Better you do this on the serializer

Comment: Please add your serializer, maybe I can give a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make things easier I used `cloudinary` to host my images since eventually I will store them in the cloud in production.

Therefore:

1. Installed required cloudinary python packages i.e `cloudinary` and  `dj3-cloudinary-storage`
2. Added `cloudinary` in installed apps:

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
        ......
        'rest_framework',
        'django_extensions',
        'corsheaders',
        'cloudinary', # Add cloudinary 
        'drf_yasg',
        'celery',
        'django_prometheus',
        'debug_toolbar',
        
    
    ]
```

3. Changed the default file storage in **settings.py** and added cloudinary configs:

```
CLOUDINARY_STORAGE = {
    'CLOUD_NAME': '*******',
    'API_KEY': '*********',
    'API_SECRET': '*********',
}


DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'cloudinary_storage.storage.MediaCloudinaryStorage'
```

4. Removed below don't need it anymore in root **urls.py**

`urlpatterns+= static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`

After testing an upload here are the results:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Django rest framework, by default, builds absolute URLs for file field if you **pass request in serializer context**. Try to pass the request in serializer like this.

```
serializer = YourSerializer(<OTHER_ARGS>, context={'request': request})
```

You will get the absolute URL automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Django doesn't provide absoluteurl for image stored in models.ImageField. But you can modify your serializer and do this with [serializer.SerializerMethodField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield). as you didn't provide your serializer so i assume it maybe look like this:

```
class Document(seralizer.ModelSerializer):
    file_url = serializer.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
           model = Document
           fields = ('id','name','timestamp','file_url')

    def get_file_url(self, document):
        request = self.context.get('request')
        file_url = document.file.url
        return request.build_absolute_uri(file_url)
```